# Confusion with move constructors: unable to call move constructor

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, move-constructor, most-vexing-parse

I've been having difficulties understanding move constructors in C++. I have made a simple class with a default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor and destructor. Also, I have defined a function with two overloads, one accepts a reference to that class and one accepts an rvalue reference to that class. My test code is below.

```
#include <iostream>


class c {

public:

    c() {
        std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    c(const c& s) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    c(c&& s) {
        std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~c() {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }

};

void f(c& s) {
    std::cout << "passed by reference" << std::endl;
}

void f(c&& s) {
    std::cout << "passed by rvalue reference" << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    c s1; // line 1
    std::cout << "\n";
    c s2(s1); // line 2
    std::cout << "\n";
    c s3(c()); // line 3

    std::cout << "\n";

    f(s1); // line 4
    std::cout << "\n";
    f(c()); // line 5

    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

The output I'm getting is not what I was expecting. Below is the output I'm getting from this code.

```
default constructor

copy constructor

passed by reference

default constructor
passed by rvalue reference
destructor
```

I can understand the outputs from all lines except `line 3`. On `line 3`, which is `c s3(c());`, `c()` is an rvalue so I'd expect that `s3` would be move constructed. But the output doesn't show that it is move constructed. On `line 5`, I'm doing the same thing and passing an `rvalue` to the function `f()` and it indeed calls the overload that accepts an `rvalue` reference. I'm very confused and would appreciate any information on this.

**Edit:** I am able to call the move constructor if I do `c s3(std::move(c()));` but am I not already passing an rvalue to s3? Why would I need `std::move`?

Comment: @NathanOliver That's not really a duplicate of this one. What's happening here is the Most Vexing Parse, not copy elision.

Comment: @Angew Good call.  Missed that.

Comment: @Angew What I actually was trying to do was constructing an object through its move constructor and when NathanOliver directed me to the other question, I really thought this was a duplicate. I didn't even notice the statement on line 3 was a function signature until you have pointed out. I have never heard of most vexing parse either, so thank you for sharing that with me; I'll be reading on it to learn what it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why you don't see any output from line 3 is that it declares a function, not a variable. This is due to an ambiguity called [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Compare `c s3(c())` with `int foo(int ())`, which, thanks to implicit type adjustments, is the same as `int foo(int (*f)())`.

To get around this, use brace initialisation (which was actually introduced in C++11 partly for this very reason):

```
c s3(c{});

// or

c s3{c()};

// or

c s3{c{}};
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. Both this and also M.M's answer below answer my question. However, apparently you were a minute earlier than they were, so I'll accept your answer. Thank you and M.M for your time and help.

Answer (score 5):

`c s3(c());` does not construct any object. It is a function declaration. The function is called `s3`, the return type is `c`, and the parameter type is "pointer to function taking no parameters and returning `c`".  So you get no output, since a function declaration does not call any functions.

To avoid this sort of thing you can use list initialization,  `c s3{c()};` is probably more in line with what you had in mind.

Comment: +1 for info 'parameter type is "pointer to function taking no parameters and returning c"'. if it were `c(x)` then parameter type is `c` and name is `x`